# How can I use .deployed() with a constructor argument?

Tags: ether-pudding

My contract has a constructor argument, is there a way to use puddings handy `Contract.deployed()` function together wit a default argument? 
How can one achieve this?

Somehow [there are args in the construction of a new contract](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding/blob/418c8d10fd60e66031391e9ccd24afac04db882a/classtemplate.js), but I don't get it how to initialize them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract's constructor only runs during the process of contract creation/deployment, so `Contract.new(arg1ForConstructor, arg2...)`.

`Contract.deployed()` is for a contract that has already been deployed: the constructor can't be invoked again.

Comment: You are right, I may have not understood the problem correctly. It could be more a truffle problem I want to address.